# bashrc not loaded on login

Tags: bash

I created a new home directory for myself on my SSH server and when I log in my bashrc is never loaded, I always have to type `. ~/.bashrc` after I log in. How can I save keystrokes so this is done automatically?

Comment: thats only for interactive shells - you might want to put those commands into `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` instead

Comment: Is your default shell `bash`?  `.bashrc` won't run for `zsh`, `sh`, `ash`, `csh`, etc.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yes it is. If I were to use a different shell would there be a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could link your `.bash_login` - used when you login - to your `.bashrc` - used for other `bash` shell sessions:

```
mv -f .bash_login .bash_login.old    # Don't worry if this says no such file
ln -s .bashrc .bash_login
```

Ensure that the commands in your `.bashrc` can handle the possibility that they are being run *without* a terminal being connected. So don't print anything unless there's a terminal attached to *stdout*, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not POSIX compliant here.

Any interactive shell should read the file $ENV in the users home directory, but `bash` reads `$HOME/.bash_login` instead in case it is a login shell and even reads this file before reading `$HOME/.profile` instead of reading it after that file.

Fortunately, this deviating behavior is documented in the `bash` man page under the section **INVOCATION** that starts aprox. at page #3.